# Issue with setting value to select dropdown in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I am using MVC.

I am having two drop down and one change of 'primaryspec' the 'primarysubspec' should get loaded.

Everything is working fine for passing values to controller and it got saved to DB.

When I am trying to retrieve the saved details,'primarysubspec' saved values are not getting displayed.

But displaying save data for 'primarySpec'.

Here is my .cshtml code:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PSpec, Model.PSpec, new { id = "ddUserSpec", style = "width:245px;height:25px;",  data_bind = "event: {change: primaryChanged}" }, Model.IsReadOnly)


  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PSubspec, Model.PSubspec, new { id = "ddUserSubSpec", style = "width:245px;height:25px;",  data_bind = "options: primarySubSpec,optionsText: 'Name',optionsValue: 'Id'" }, Model.IsReadOnly)
```

Here is my JS Code to retrieve the values for :

```
this.primarySubSpec = ko.observableArray([]);

    this.primarySpecChanged = function () {

      var val = $("#ddetailsPrimarySpec").val();
      primarySubStartIndex = 0;
      primarySubSpecialityUrl = '/PlatformUser/GetSpecandSubSpec?primarySpe=' + val+//model.primarySpecID() +'&secondarySpec=';
            loadPrimarySubSpec();
        };

function loadPrimarySubSpec() {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: primarySubSpecUrl,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            processdata: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {

                primarySubSpec = [];
                model.primarySubspec('0');
                try {
                   if (data.length == 0) {
                    primarySubSpeacId.empty();
                }
                model.primarySubSpec(data);
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                primarySubSpeacId.prop("disabled", true);

            }

        });
    }
```

Everything is working fine,but facing issue only while displaying the saved values from the DB.

Showing fine for 'primarySpec'
The values showing empty for 'PrimarySubSpec' instead of saved values in dropdown.

Please let me know what is the issue how can i show the saved value as selected value in 'primarySubSpec'dropdown.

Comment: IMHO, you can improve your overall implementation if you bind the drop-downs to observable arrays for their options. If you do that, loading/initialization with already saved values will happen (almost) automatically for you

Comment: I have tried that method as well.I will put the code as well.still the value is not getting reflected for 'primarySubSpecilaity'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem:**
when you load the page to view saved values, the change event is never called.

**Why:**
When your page is loaded with saved values, the select box has the saved value selected before knockout knows anything about it. Hens the change event isn't called.

**Simplest solution:**
change the `primarySpecilaityChanged` as follows

```
this.primarySpecilaityChanged = function () {
  var val = $("#ddUserDetailsPrimarySpeciality").val();
  if(val){
    primarySubStartIndex = 0;
    primarySubSpecialityUrl = '/' + NMCApp.getVirtualDirectoryName() + '/PlatformUser/GetSpecialitiesandSubSpecilaities?primarySpeciality=' + val+//model.primarySpecialityUID() +'&secondarySpeciality=';
    loadPrimarySubSpecilaities();
  }
};
```

then call `primarySpecilaityChanged` function after you call `ko.applyBindings`.

```
var viewModel = new YourViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
viewModel.primarySpecilaityChanged();
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion,I am not getting problem with the change event.I am using the same code for add and View.Adding the model is success.When viewing the saved values,facing issue with only 'PrimarySubspeciality' dropdown

Comment: I know, but you load values for 'PrimarySubSpeciality` through ajax and that ajax call is made when the `change` event is called. what I'm trying to say is that `change` event isn't called when you first load the page with your saved values.